# Facebook Graph API, Development of Facebook page post targeting( make visible only specified country/city )

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

So I have developed APP with FB Graph API. This app writes posts on specified Facebook page. I decided that I need attach target of country and city to posts. So I have written code like this:

```
if( count( $DataArray ) > 0 ) {

            $MessageData = null;
            $AccessToken = $this->GetAccessToken();

            foreach( $DataArray as $ItemArray ) {
                $CleanTitle  = $this->ValidateTitle( $ItemArray['title'], $NotAcceptableWords );
                $GenerateMessageStr = "{$CleanTitle} - http://someutl/ID/{$Item['id']}/Feed/";

                $MessageData = array (

                    'access_token' => $AccessToken,
                    'message'      => $GenerateMessageStr,
                    'targeting' => "{'cities':'Tbilisi','countries':'Georgia'}"
                );

                try {
                    $this->FacebookObject->api("/{$this->FacebookPageId}/feed", 'POST', $MessageData);
                } 
                catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                    print_r($e);
                }

            }
        }
```

But after executing, the posts still seems like public and no some targeting is attached.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Try `feed_targeting` instead of `targeting`!

All parameters which you can target like languages,cities,counties are facebook specific. You can resolve them via [autocomplete data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data/) :

"{'locales':[1001],'countries':[GE],'cities':[825886]}"

Nice feature for automatic posting with targeting but so bad documented in the Facebook documentation...

Answer (score 1):

The right solution is: You generate the key for the city (using the API) and use the country's 2 letter code. $messageData will be:

```
$messageData = [
    'access_token' => $AccessToken,
    'message'      => $GenerateMessageStr,
    'targeting'    => "{'cities': <generated city key>,'countries':'GE'}"
]
```

If you're using API v2.8 and the current Facebook PHP SDK (5):

```
$request = new \Facebook\FacebookRequest(
    $fbApp,
    $accessToken,
   'POST',
   '/<facebook-page-id>/feed',
    [
        'message' => 'With Geolocate Ib',
        'targeting' => "{'geo_locations': {'cities': [{'key':" . <city key> . "}]}}"
    ]
);
```

The *targeting* flags makes sure only those in the specified city, region etc sees the post. *feeds_targeting* might still allow people not in those city/region to see the posts.